# How does explode work?

Tags: php, string, split, explode

Why do I get 2 different results in this very simple script:

```
$str = "114004©301000©301000©301000©";
echo $str."<br/ >"; //Prints 114004Â©301000Â©301000Â©301000Â©
$test1 = (explode("©",$str));
print_r($test1); //Prints Array ( [0] => 114004 [1] => 301000 [2] => 301000 [3] => 301000 [4] => ) 

echo "<br /><br />";

$blah = $data['final_alle_produktid']; // Contains a string called 114004©301000©301000©301000©
$test1 = (explode("©",$blah));
print_r($test1); //Prints Array ( [0] => 114004©301000©301000©301000© )
```

I don't understand why the second explode won't split up the string just because i originated from a mysql query.

**Edit:** I can't even use `str_replace` on this example:

```
$blah = str_replace("©"," ",$data['final_alle_produktid']); 
echo $blah."<br/ >"; //Still prints 114004©301000©301000©301000©
```

Makes no sense. utf8_decode changes nothing. Not even if I save it in a variable first e.g.:

```
$test = $data['final_alle_produktid'];
$blah = str_replace("©"," ",$test); 
echo $blah."<br/ >"; //Still prints 114004©301000©301000©301000©
```

**Edit2:**

```
print_r($blah); //Prints 114004©301000©301000©301000©
```

**Edit 3**

No solution. Had nothing to do with the limit. If I exchange the © with a B then everything works.

**Solution:**

I had to included correct encoding (I simply added the standard html headers and encoding).

Comment: Is the encoding of your source code and the string you get from mysql identical?

Comment: Can you print_r($blah)?

Comment: These is indeed something strange happening. When I try to echo the first $str I get this: 114004Â©301000Â©301000Â©301000Â©

Comment: I suspect the © character is messing with things.

Comment: Use `utf8_decode($str);`

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because the encodings differ. The "©" in your source code is represented using different bytes than the string you get from MySQL, so they do not match and `explode` doesn't find any substring to explode on. You need to ensure you're using the same encoding throughout, or convert encodings as needed.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/47).

Comment: Sorry not real solution.

Comment: Mine or yours? Still looks like an obvious encoding problem, which means you should educate yourself about encodings.

Comment: You are correct! I tried to included standard HTML headers/encoding and now it works! Thank you very much ^^